# Grails GORM - How to get a PagedResultList when using aggregation functions

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I'm using GORM from grails 1.2.1. No chance of upgrading at this point. This is not a grails app per se; rather it is a webapp that uses groovy and leverages GORM for easy domain model persistence.

I have a query like this:

```
actionsByUser = UserAction.createCriteria().list() {
                    projections {
                        countDistinct('id', 'userCount')
                        groupProperty('user')
                    }
                    firstResult(offset)
                    maxResults(max)
                    order('userCount', 'desc')
                }
```

That doesn't return me a PagedResultList with a getTotalCount method which would indicate how many results there are and let me know when to display a next link to show the next page of results.

I tried something like this instead:

```
actionsByUser = UserAction.createCriteria().list(max:max, offset:offset) {
                    projections {
                        countDistinct('id', 'userCount')
                        groupProperty('user')
                    }
                    order('userCount', 'desc')
                }
```

i.e. change to pass the max and offset parameters in via an initial Map parameter to `list`, rather than using the DSL within the Closure.

That fails with:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: userCount of: example.domain.UserAction
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:67)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:61)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getSubclassPropertyTableNumber(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1392)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.BasicEntityPropertyMapping.toColumns(BasicEntityPropertyMapping.java:54)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toColumns(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1367)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumns(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:457)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getColumnsUsingProjection(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:417)
at org.hibernate.criterion.Order.toSqlString(Order.java:68)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaQueryTranslator.getOrderBy(CriteriaQueryTranslator.java:371)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:113)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaJoinWalker.<init>(CriteriaJoinWalker.java:82)
at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.<init>(CriteriaLoader.java:91)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1578)
at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:306)
at grails.orm.HibernateCriteriaBuilder.invokeMethod(HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java:1025)
```

How can I get a result back from grails that is suitable for doing "page 1 of n" functionality?

**UPDATE:** [Raised on Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3045) as suggested - I didn't get a response on #grails on freenode.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented very well but put your pagination params in the `createCriteria.list([in here!])` this should return you a `PagedResultList`

example...

```
def result=Thing.createCriteria().list(max:params.max, offset:params.offset){
   maxResults(params.max)
   firstResult(params.offset)
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

Your error seems to be with an invalid query `could not resolve property: userCount`.  Take a second look at your projection query.  **At first glance it does seem okay** and there was a [jira issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3655) that seems to be resolved in Grails 1.2.

Also, here are some links explaining the poorly documented PagedResultList...

[Here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Criteria-list-returns-ArrayList-while-PagedResultList-is-expected-td1392786.html) and [Here](http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/tag/pagedresultlist/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't understand that. I'm not clear how that is different to the failing example that I gave? I tried your suggestion (which just seems to specify the max and offset twice?) and still get the same exception. Please can you help me understand what I'm missing?

Comment: My projection query works in the first instance, but not in the second instance. AFAICT the only difference that I can see is that in the second bit of code, I'm passing the `max` and `offset` parameters in via a `Map` as the first parameter, in an attempt to get a `PagedResultList` back as per the [documentation](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html). So my question could be redefined as "why doesn't the projection query work when I attempt to get a PagedResultList back"

Comment: I suspect that projections don't work with `list(Map, Closure)`.

Comment: @jabely I would not be surprised if that where the case (+1 your question).  Maybe post the issue to Jira?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is HibernateCriteria query does not understand alias defined in projections which is the reason for error "unable to resolve property", the issue yet to be fixed

here is the jira ticket
http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3875